# Does anyone know how to make this sentence active?

Tags: active-voice

How to turn this sentence into active voice:

He expected to be taken care of.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and what problems you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

> He expected someone to take care of him.

In your sentence there is an infinitve clause that uses the passive voice "to be taken care of".  The implied grammatical subject is the same as the main verb, ie "He" and there is no "by" phrase.

So an active infinitive clause will have an object "him" (to match "he") need a pronoun like "somebody" as the subject.

Comment: thanks James K, and I make myself clear now.